# Simplest Hive query just doesn't work

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hbase

When i try to got a query `SELECT * FROM A` 
I get all of information  but when try to getting a query that exists a column name (or a join)   `SELECT a FROM A` It returns some Exceptions:

```
Total MapReduce jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /tmp/hive-merza/hive_2014-06-25_09-12-19_567_6884805431385202274/-mr-10003/3a481893-3b7e-4cb7-bca7-d5ad103e3aa8 could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1920)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:783)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1428)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1426)

Continuing ...
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /tmp/hadoop-merza/mapred/staging/merza/.staging/job_201406250859_0004/libjars/hbase-0.94.16.jar could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1920)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:783)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1428)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1426)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1113)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
    at $Proxy12.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:62)
    at $Proxy12.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.locateFollowingBlock(DFSClient.java:3720)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSClient.java:3580)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2600(DFSClient.java:2783)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSClient.java:3023)
Job Submission failed with exception 'org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException: File /tmp/hadoop-merza/mapred/staging/merza/.staging/job_201406250859_0004/libjars/hbase-0.94.16.jar could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1920)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:783)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1428)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1426)
)'
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
```

HADOOP 1.2.1

HBASE 0.94.16

HIVE 0.11.0

NOTE:my mapred and dfs is running.

Comment: Can you check the datanode details using `dfs-admin -report`?

Comment: Where??In My GUI(in web browser)? or in bin directory.

Comment: Yes, in the Hadoop bin..

Comment: OMG!
hadoop ***            start-all.sh  *****             stop-balancer.sh***
hadoop-config.sh  ** start-balancer.sh**          stop-dfs.sh**
hadoop-daemon.sh **  start-dfs.sh  **             stop-jobhistoryserver.sh**
hadoop-daemons.sh ** start-jobhistoryserver.sh ** stop-mapred.sh
rcc      **          start-mapred.sh     **       task-controller
slaves.sh  **        stop-all.sh**
 only these !!!!:(

Comment: Trying to solve that by setting up $HIVE_HOME/auxlib with the correct jars
> and defining auxlib in hive-site.xml.   hive 0.11.0 comes with
> hbase-0.94.16, .  Could that also cause
> incompatibilities?

Comment: From the exception it seems like there is some problem with replication. This might happen if the replication factor "dfs.replication" is not set correctly or if it is not uniform throughout all the nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!
Must be add some jar files to `env-hive.sh`

```
export HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH=/.../hbase-***.jar,/.../hbase-handler***.jar,/.../zookeeperp***.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason **select * from table** works and **select a from table** doesn't is because when u do a select * you need all the data which is lying there on hdfs hence it doesn't run's any M/R job 
but in case of select a it has to run m/r job to strip the extra columns.

So effectively the issue is you are not able M/R job on your cluster,  this issue is  usually caused by insufficient space.

please check the total capacity of your cluster and used, remaining ratio using

```
  hdfs dfsadmin -report
```

also check dfs.datanode.du.reserved in the hdfs-site.xml, if this value is larger than your remained capacity

look for other possible causes explained [here](http://cloudcelebrity.wordpress.com/2013/11/25/handling-hadoop-error-could-only-be-replicated-to-0-nodes-instead-of-1-during-copying-data-to-hdfs-or-with-mapreduce-jobs/)